# Counting sublists inside a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list like `p = [[[[[[[[1, 2, 3]]]]]]]]`, I want to get the count of the items in the list including  empty lists, so for this list I should get 10. I am trying to enumerate the list like -

```
for idx, item in enumerate(p):
    count = count + idx
```

but I am not able to get the empty lists there. Please advice.

Comment: There are no empty lists in there.

Comment: Could you explain how you get 10 for that list?

Comment: He counts the number of items in each list and adds them together

Comment: jamylak - yes you are right, I want to count the depth of these lists, so if you see, I have 7 nested lists and 1,2,and 3, so my depth should be 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shorter version of code below:

```
>>> def recur_len(l):
        return sum(1 + recur_len(item) if isinstance(item,list) else 1 for item in l)

>>> recur_len([[[[[[[[1, 2, 3]]]]]]]])
10
```

More detailed code

```
>>> def recur_len(l):
        count = 0
        for item in l:
            if isinstance(item,list):
                count += 1 + recur_len(item)
            else:
                count += 1
        return count

>>> recur_len([[[[[[[[1, 2, 3]]]]]]]])
10
```

Comment: +1 I'll leave my answer up, but this is what was actually wanted by the OP. The question wording wasn't very clear and the example ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah i agree i didn't understand the whole 'empty list thing'

Comment: Thanks, will be more descriptive next time. Now it is time to sit and learn how this code it working, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to count **lists** (or subclasses of `list`) and nothing else, except the content of the final list not just containing another list:

```
def len_counting_containers(inlist):
    count = 0
    current = inlist
    while len(current) == 1 and isinstance(current[0], list):
        count += 1
        current = current[0]
    return count + len(current)

len_counting_containers([[[[[[[[1, 2, 3]]]]]]]])
```

Which gives us:

```
10
```

Note that this is a pretty fragile operation (as with any case you use `isinstance()` in python) - so you want to be sure that your incoming data is always structured as you expect. If your data is coming from a source you control, I would recommend looking at how you produce the data and seeing if you can give it in a nicer form - e.g: `(7, [1,2,3])`.

You could also implement this recursively:

```
def len_counting_containers(current):
    return len_counting_containers(current[0])+1 if len(current) == 1 and isinstance(current[0], list) else len(current)

len_counting_containers([[[[[[[[1, 2, 3]]]]]]]])
```

This gives the same result in less code, but if you are working with an insanely large lists this could hit recursion limits.

Comment: Thanks, I am a newbee here so trying to grasp as much as I can, what if I change list to myList = ([1, [1, 2, [3, 4]]]), I am getting only 2 for this operation but I have 7 items there, please explain, I will try to code myself

Comment: Ah, you said including 'empty lists', so I presumed you meant lists containing only one item. I think [jamylak's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9955769/722121) does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
def depth(a):
    return 1 + depth(a[0]) if type(a) is list else 0
```

Demo:

```
a = 'x'
for n in range(10):
    a = [a]
    print a, depth(a)


## ['x'] 1
## [['x']] 2
## [[['x']]] 3
## [[[['x']]]] 4
## [[[[['x']]]]] 5
## [[[[[['x']]]]]] 6
## [[[[[[['x']]]]]]] 7
## [[[[[[[['x']]]]]]]] 8
## [[[[[[[[['x']]]]]]]]] 9
## [[[[[[[[[['x']]]]]]]]]] 10
```

Comment: `code` def deep_count(p):
 sum = 0
 for e in p:
  sum = sum + 1
  if is_list(e):
   sum = sum + deep_count(e)
 return sum `code`